# How to generate a business card dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I wonder how does this website [create business cards online](https://fansycard.com/) 
is that possible with query?

you just put information in the form and it generates multiple card designs in image format, which is editable also.

You clarification will be much appreciated.

this is the tool: [https://fansycard.com](https://fansycard.com/)

Answer (score 3):

The [fansycard](https://fansycard.com/) seems to be using html2canvas library, which does this job very nicely.

Check this out: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

HTML

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```